# Glitch when resizing navbar+footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm encountering a problem on a website I'm developing: when I re-size the window to an horizontal resolution lower than 1170px both the navbar and the footer create gaps to the right of the page. [image: Resized Window]
[image: Fullscreen]
This also happens on mobile browsers (when zooming in the navbar shifts to the right making the last objects unreachable).
Could you kindly help me fix this problem?

HTML: http://pastebin.com/nTW3MrEr
CSS: http://pastebin.com/v1TDiK6J
Footer problem (Window Resized, the hero unit/navbar/and content are fine, but the footer still glitches, i've put some text to better understand the problem: [image]

Comment: pastebin not opening for me . Also why dont you post a test page or jsfiddle .

Comment: Live Version: http://www.abbraccio-onlus.it/nuova/sis.html

Comment: I didnt found the nav shift in IE9 FF and chrome latest on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the website is because of the min-width:1100px set to hero-unit and width:1170px set to div #corpo. Since you are using container class to wrap up your content , in bootstrap responsive css the width is already 1170px so no need to set it there .

Also to rearrange your layout to be properly visible you can write media queries for specific sections of your page.
On your page on tablet view there is a big top margin between navigation and page-header so you can arrange them as belows like:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .navbar-fixed-top{
        margin-top:5px;
             }
     .page-header{
          margin-top:5px;
           }
      }

/* Landscape phones and down */
   @media (max-width: 480px) {
          .navbar-fixed-top{
        margin-top:5px;
             }
     .page-header{
          margin-top:5px;
           }

       }
```

Comment: It works perfectly except for the footer that still glitches.

Comment: what issue do you see with footer ??